# IP camera port forwarding not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I have an IP camera that is accessible on port 8080. I have configured port forwarding in my modem to my IP camera.

When I try to connect to my IP camera address that I find under *Outside Address & Port* I can't connect to it, I have also tried to check if my port is opened but it's not, I can only connect to the camera using the Inside Address & Port.

I have been following this guide:

http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Thomson-Alcatel/TG789vn/Call_of_Duty_-_Modern_Warfare_3.htm

Does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: Port 8080 is often used to remote administration of these devices, you may not be able to use it. You could try something port forwarding 9090 outside to 8080 inside. Also, are you getting a true public IP at the modem, or an address in private space?

Comment: @acejavelin alright i will try with an other port then. i dont understand the last question that u asked me, Also, are you getting a true public IP at the modem, or an address in private space?...

Comment: i have a ip adress for public and inside for the device and it enabled, only the inside ip adress works not the public @acejavelin i have tried with the program PFPortChecker when typing in my port 9090.

I get: Your port it NOT OPEN or not reachable.

Comment: Somewhere in the router there is a status page telling you what the WAN, Public, or Internet IP address is... if it is in Private Space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) then this all may be for nothing anyway. Your modem/router must have a fully route-able public IP address for this to work, it cannot be behind a Carrier-Grade NAT system (which is common with DSL).

Comment: Hmm i am not sure if i have a private Space, but i have a DSL connection at home. How can i make a fully route-able public ip adress? @acejavelin

Comment: "You" can't... it is all based on the service your ISP is providing you. I posted a link before, if your modem thinks it's IP is 192.168.X.X, 10.X.X.X, or 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255, you are getting a NAT IP address and your NATing will not work.

Comment: yes my ip inside my router beings with 192.168.X.X, so what should i then do to make it work? @acejavelin

Comment: No, the internal address is not relavent. I am talking about the modem's **OUTSIDE** WAN or Internet address... the one actually assigned to the modem by your ISP, not what you would get from something like www.ipchicken.com or it's LAN IP

Comment: Alright my External ip address begging s with 31.210.X.X @acejavelin

Comment: OK, then you should be good... just do the port forwarding, and on a remote computer (it can't be inside the same LAN or network as the camera), browse to http://31.210.X.X:8080 (or 9090 or whatever port you assigned on the public side of port forwarding) and it should open the camera if the camera has the correct network settings.

Comment: @acejavelin Alright but i have already try-id it out but it cant reach my 31.210.X.X:9090 Adress i am in the same network in my camera settings i havent done so much, i have only connected it to my wifi, because the camera has a wireless connection, i have also only changed till Http port on the camera to: 9090. The settings for the network for the camera has the ip that are inside my network and not my public ip adress

Comment: You can't test it from within the same network (LAN), this is called hairpinning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) and most routers will not allow it to occur. If you change the port on the camera to 9090 than you can do straight-thru port forwarding (9090 public side, 9090 private side), but this should eleviate the problem of 8080 possibly being used for other services.

Comment: Hmm alright i have tried on lan and also on my 4G net on my phone cant still not connect to public ip adress. Both Public and internal ip adress has 9090. @acejavelin i only get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT